# RetryTopicConfigurationSupport produces exception: Either a RetryTopicSchedulerWrapper or TaskScheduler bean is required

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.5 with Spring Kafka. I want to configure Non-Blocking topics with RetryTopicConfigurationSupport, as it is written here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-global-settings

My configuration looks as follows:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class RetryTopicsConfig extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected Consumer<DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory> configureDeadLetterPublishingContainerFactory() {

        return dlprf -> dlprf.setRetainAllRetryHeaderValues(false);
    }
}
```

When application starts, it produces:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either a RetryTopicSchedulerWrapper or TaskScheduler bean is required
```

Am I doing something wrong?

When I added:

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
}
```

it starts, but I'm not sure if I suppose to do that? According to documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#programmatic-construction) it is designed for Progammatic Construction, but I use annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding the `@EnableScheduling` at the class level of the `RetryTopicsConfig.class` is much better in this case

Answer (score 0):

In this case, yes, it is fine to just define a `TaskScheduler` bean.